# Removing a pinned network location from explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, network-shares

I pinned two network locations to my quick access in windows 10. One is no longer accessible, and I would like to remove it, but the context menu only lists "Expand." Is there a registry key or something I can remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click Quick Access. In the right-pane, select the network location, press and hold the CTRL key (for multi-select) to select another Pinned folder from local drive. Right-click menu should now show Unpin from Quick Access. Both will be removed though.
(Source: http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/unpin-ftp-links-stuck-quick-access-windows-10/)

Comment: First of all: How could Microsoft forget to add an option to remove network locations from quick access?! Second of all: Just tried your tip by selecting two FTP folders and then trying to right-click them. This made Explorer crash. Oh my... :) - But if I use a "normal" folder as second location, your tip works.